# Edge-critical Subgraphs Preserving Maximum Degree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A graph $G$ is called $\it{edge}$-$\it{critical}$ if $\chi'(G-e) < \chi'(G)$ for every edge $e$ where $\chi'(G)$ denotes the edge-chromatic number of $G$. Edge-critical graphs are very useful because every graph contains an edge-critical subgraph and this family of graphs has more interesting structures. Now my question is: Does every graph contain an edge-critical subgraph with the same maximum degree?

Comment: might be helpful to define $\chi \prime$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is known](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VizingsTheorem.html) that $\chi'(G) \in \{\,\Delta(G), \Delta(G) + 1\,\}$. So there are two cases only.

If $\chi'(G) = \Delta(G) + 1$, then we can delete edge by edge, while edge-chromatic number doesn't change. Remaining subgraph $H$ is edge-critical, has the same edge-chromatic number, and its maximum vertex degree is not greater than in the graph $G$:
$$\chi'(G) = \chi'(H) \le \Delta(H) + 1 \le \Delta(G) + 1 = \chi'(G).$$
Therefore $\Delta(H) = \Delta(G)$.

If $\chi'(G) = \Delta(G)$, then we can keep only a vertex $v$ of maximum degree and all incident edges. Such a subgraph $H \cong K_{1, \Delta(G)}$ is edge-critical. And we have:
$$\chi'(G) \ge \chi'(H) = \Delta(H) = \Delta(G) = \chi'(G).$$
Therefore $\Delta(H) = \Delta(G)$.

So the answer is yes, every graph contains an edge-critical subgraph with the same maximum vertex degree.